# Serving tensorflow models on GCP?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

Recently I've been trying to host a custom image classification tensorflow saved model on GCP and use a REST API to send prediction requests. I've hosted this model on Google's [AI Platform API](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict).

I'm trying to build an application on React Native. Essentially I take a picture from my phone and send this to my model using REST. Unfortunately after consulting this documentation it appears that I would need OAuth tokens for the prediction request to go through. I don't want this functionality. I don't want users needing to sign in to send prediction requests.

I was wondering if there are ways I can host this tensorflow model and send `fetch()` requests from my React Native environment.

If anyone has done this before, please let me know! I'd greatly appreciate all of the help.

I'm willing to try different hosting platforms, but the tensorflow website had pointed me towards GCP.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't recommend you to publicly open billable resources like this, because you are exposed to attack and huge consumption.

But, if you really want to achieve this, you can allow `allUsers` on your deployed models

```
gcloud ai-platform models add-iam-policy-binding <MY_MODEL_NAME> \
  --member="allUsers" \
  --role="roles/ml.modelUser"
```

Comment: Interesting, is there any other platforms I can use to serve these models then?

Comment: Also can you point me towards the documentation behind this code?

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy). Not very obvious to find, but IAM policy binding works in the same way on several services. The experience on others service has led me to deduce the right answer!

Comment: Other platform to serve a tensorflow model? I wrote 2 articles to [load dynamically a model and serve it](https://medium.com/google-cloud/on-demand-small-batch-predictions-with-cloud-run-and-embedded-tf-469242d66c3b), and [another one to create a container with the model embedded](https://medium.com/google-cloud/portable-prediction-with-tensorflow-and-cloud-run-669c1c73ebd1) (more efficient, the model isn't downloaded and loaded on the fly). Both solution are on Cloud Run (which serve serverless container), but you can host the container where you want. On a VM or on Kubernetes/GKE

Comment: If I do this solution, then will I have to send any authentication token in my HTTPS request? How would I make an HTTPS request? I'd appreciate if you could provide an example. I was using this following documentation: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict

Comment: If you allow allUsers, that means all unauthenticated request are accepted on the service. Therefore, simply perform your POST request and without the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` in the header. That's all!